# Get multiple lines using regex with Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I have been trying to modify some files with Ansible but I do not have the right regex.

The goal is to modify a set of files and change everything between  `<Factory />` and `</Factory>` as "not register". As an example

I want to change this:

```
<Factory />
Replacement set
Madrid
</Factory>
```

to this:

```
<Factory />
Not register
<Factory />
```

What I have is the following:

```
hosts: all
tasks:
  - name: replace factory registration
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path: /home/clientDatabase.xml
      regex: {'(?<=<Factory />.*?(?=</Factory>)', multiline = True}
      replace: 'Not register'
```

I have tried several expressions and this is the closest I have got. It works perfectly on notepad++ if you set the regular expression on and check the .match newline box but it does not do anything in ansible.

What I understand is from (?<=) to (?=) get me everything in between (.*) that is 0 or once (?), check on multiple lines to get the whole structure (multiline = True).

I have also tried \R for return carrier and break line, the ^ and $ ones but from all the tries I had it does not work and I am getting out of ideas.

Could someone give me any hints here?

Here are some resources I think helped me the most:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html
https://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex.php

**Update:**

Finally, I follow your suggestion, using `[^<]*?` match everything except the `"<"` character and it worked perfectly. The parenthesis was a mispell, sorry

The final result is:

```
hosts: all
tasks:
  - name: replace factory registration
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path: /home/clientDatabase.xml
      regex: '(?<=<Factory />)[^<]*?'
      replace: 'Not register'
```

What I understand is from `<Factory />` replace all content up to the first `<`. With this statement not multiline, nor dotall flag need to be use.

Comment: In your regex of lookbehind, the right parenthesis seems missing. It should be `(?<=<Factory />)`. Besides `.*?` does not match newline characters by default. Try to put `dotall = True` option, or use `[^<]*?` instead of `.*?`.

Comment: Is this question answered? should it be closed or the answer shown written as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following regex which allows words, spaces and newline between the tags `<Factory />` and `</Factory>`.
Please note that the string is on 2 lines because it contains a newline as part of the pattern.

```regex
(?<=<Factory \/>)[\w\s
]*(?=<\/Factory>)
```

this could also be written

```regex
(?<=<Factory \/>)[\w\s\n\r]*(?=<\/Factory>)
```